# PHP Calling a callback function from within Object method

Tags: php, laravel, callback

I am building a scheduler that will take a callback function and will execute that function a given amount of times, and in between a given amount of delay. Below is that the interface for what the functionality looks like.

Side note I am using the Laravel Framework;

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $count = 0;
    $schedule = new NodeScheduler();
    $schedule->retries(2)->delay(100000)->do(function() use ($count) {
        $count++;
    });
    $this->assertEquals($count === 1);
}
```

This is my test for this piece of functionality and as you can see i want count to equal 2 by the end of it.

My class looks like this;

```
class NodeScheduler
{
    protected $retries = 1;
    protected $milliseconds = 10000;

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function retries($numberOfRetries)
    {
        $this->retries = $numberOfRetries;
        return $this;
    }

    public function delay($milliSeconds)
    {
        $this->milliSeconds = $milliSeconds;
        return $this;
    }

    public function do($callback)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->retries; $i++){
            $callback(); // <<<<<< How Do I Inject The $count Variable Here?
            usleep($this->milliseconds);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

My test fails with:

```
Failed asserting that 2 matches expected 0.
```

Strangely I don't get $count is undefined.

I think i am close, any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you want to write `$this->assertEquals(1, $count); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `use()` a variable from the outer scope inside a function, this creates a **copy** of the variable into the function's inner scope (an exception is if you're `use()`ing an object).

If you want to import a variable from the outer scope **and** modify it, you'll need to pass it in by reference:

```
$schedule->retries(2)->delay(100000)->do(function() use (&$count) {
    $count++;
});
```

**Edit**: Also, what @Arno and @Oniyo pointed out: either use `assertEquals(1, $count)` or use `assertTrue($count === 1)`

Comment: I had no idea about the pass by reference, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing two things wrong

**Firstly:** As [@Arno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6345374/arno) pointed out,

```
$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
```

**Secondly:** From what I see in your code, the loop will run `$this->retries`'s iterations. So, `$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual)` should be

```
$this->assertEquals(2, count);
```

Good luck man!